# When running server job with dsjob command, datastage job fails with code=-14 DSJE_TIMEOUT

Tags: sql, database, etl, business-intelligence, datastage

What are the possible reasons and ways to solve the error?

Comment: No details provided - read how to ask questions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [IBM support page](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/datastage-dsjob-status-code-14-dsjetimeout) regarding this error

Comment: Thanks Michael for the link. But none of the home directories had the mentioned file for deletion. Is there any other way for resolving the error?

Comment: Provide the whole command you try to run. Have you sourced the .dsenv file?

Comment: /opt/IBM/InformationServer/Server/DSEngine/bin/dsjob -run -mode RESET -param Cycle=ctiOpenAR -param LOB=CTI -userstatus -jobstatus cti RunJobs.ctiOpenAR

Comment: Do other jobs work? Did you try the DOMAIN option? Please provide more details

Comment: Hi Michael, The issue got resolved after a DB restart which was not started properly after an activity. Thanks for your support. Stay safe.